# Coulmns are hidden while downloading xlsx file using axlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, excel, xlsx, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem for downloading xlsx files.

I am able to view all columns in the xlsx sheet when I view it using google sheets. But when I open the same file on a windows machine, only the first column is displayed rest all the columns are hidden. When I change the setting of sheet to display all cells, only then I can view all columns.

There is no explicit visibility attribute that I have added in my code.

I then tried the following code snippet:

```
for index in (0..99) do
  sheet.column_info[index].hidden = false
end
```

But the issue still persists on windows. Can anyone please suggest any solution or a possible solution for this issue? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.
The issue was I was setting the width of just the first column as follows:

```
sheet.column_widths 30
```

So in google sheets the first column was displayed with the width 30 and other columns were displayed as columns with default width. But the same was not displayed in windows. In windows columns were hiding because it took width of column as `nil`.
So added the following lines of code to set width of columns:

```
for index in (1..99) do
   sheet.column_info[index].width = 12
end
```